# WebMethod not called (triggered) by PageMethod in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, webmethod, pagemethods

I have the following problem:

The call from a WebMethod is not being done on a project created in Visual Studio 2013 (ASP.NET WebForms Application). If I create a project, for example, in Visual Studio 2008 and migrate to VS 2013 works correctly. The problem only occurs when I create a new project in Visual Studio 2013. There is no error message in the console. The WebMethod is just not being called. Nothing happens. I searched a lot but found nothing about it.

ASPX code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestePageMethods._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function testeClick() {            
            PageMethods.SayHello("Name");        
        }  

    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Say Hello" onclick="testeClick();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX.VB code:

```vb
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(True)> _
    Public Shared Function SayHello(ByVal name As String) As String
        Return "Hello " & name
    End Function

End Class
```

Has anyone tried this or know of a solution? I have no idea what to do ...

EDIT:

Guys, I discovered one more information now:

Working only in VS2013:

-New project.
-Web - ASP.NET Web Application.
-Select the template "Empty".
-Insert a page "Default.aspx", the WebMethod works normally ...

Now, if you create a new project and select the template "WebForms", does not work ...

Can be cross-referenced? or some different setting?

Comment: Você vai querer dar uma olhada nesse site para Português: http://br.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Questions need to be in English language.

Comment: Thank's, I will ask the question there ..

Comment: I Translated this question too..

Comment: What does "webmethod not being called" look like? Do you get an error on the client, maybe in the debugger console? Is the JavaScript executing?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There is no error in the console ... Just do not call. Nothing happens.

Comment: Check the framework version os project created on VS2008 and on new project you have created on 2013.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback rkawano. The target of the project created in VS2008 is Framework 3.5, but when I imported it to VS2013, worked both in 3.5 and in 4.5... In the project created in VS2013 is already with 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem: What prevented the WebMethod was called was the reference to "System.Web.Optimization". Not sure how he does it, but as I will not use it at the time, decided to remove:

"System.Web.Optimization" and "Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms"

It is also necessary to remove the web.config as follows:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
</namespaces>

<add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" 

namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />

<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" 

publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

All ok now! Thanks to everyone who helped me with the problem! :)

Comment: I tried the above but that made the ScriptManager stop working and I can't use the webopt tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add this section in web.config after **httpModules**.

```
add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```