# WebForm visual Studio 2013 two types, in which one type don't trigger WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, webmethod

I am using Visual Studio 2013.
I tried this sample code and cannot understand one problem I am facing.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Default.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
Your Name :
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
    onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name  + "The Current Time is: "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Now we can get 2 types of WebForms when building a 'Web Aplication':-

1. Select "WebForm" in 'Select Template' section.
2. Or select "Empty" in 'Template' section and tick 'WebForm' in 'Refernces' section.

I Know the basic difference between these two but why the given code doesn't run in (1) but runs in (2). In (1) it gives 'undefined' as output.

Some one tell me why is it so and how to make it run in (1) type of WebForm.

Comment: i have tried this also but it shows parse error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091935/webmethod-not-called-triggered-by-pagemethod-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 0):

Change $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>")[0].value for $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val() and test it.

Comment: Inside of your function include console.log($("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val()); and check the val() in the console of your browser.

Comment: Change type: "POST" with type: "GET" and test it. Work for me!

Comment: In Debug mode, Had you enter in GetCurrentTime(string name)?

Comment: the mode is debug only and i have posted whole code, can't get what u mean to say

Comment: console.log output   POST 
XHR 
http://localhost:xx593/loginpage.aspx/GetCurrentTime [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 22ms]
GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:xx605/b110da1e8f9a49a79a42014b105c00e3/arterySignalR/poll [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 6077ms]
GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:xx605/b110da1e8f9a49a79a42014b105c00e3/arterySignalR/poll [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 6736ms]

Comment: Sorry. I can´t help you. I test all code and work for me. I check console.log and get data. :(

Comment: just tell me one thing of your running code, u choose webform in template or in reference?? and which visual studio u r using? and .net 4.5?

Comment: I choose webform in template, copy & paste Default.aspx to Default2.aspx and an empty aspx.

Comment: ty really appreciate it